# Set NetLogo Display rate Constant

Tags: netlogo

I have a NetLogo model where the number of agents changes/reduces with time. I notice the model runs faster as the agents are less(ticks increment quickly).
How can keep it constant, probably set to upperlimit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways of doing that. One is to lower the speed using the speed slider at the top of model view. This essentially sets an upper limit.

Another, programmatic, way is to use the [`every`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#every) (click for link) keyword. That gives you more exact control over how your model executes, but keep in mind there is a CPU overhead using that.

Comment: But how could you determine the upper-limit this way?

Comment: Because you know that it won't execute more often than every X second. So you could do something like 'every .05 [go]'. Or is that not what you mean by upper limit?

Comment: Don't use `every` for this. It breaks the speed slider. Adjust the model's frame rate setting to the desired rate.

Comment: This is covered at http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/programming.html#updates